# Tibco EMS Session sharing Connection object

Tags: c#, tibco, ems

Our connectivity to EMS code was initially ill-designed and created one TopicConnection object per topic that we listened to. So, in effect, whenever we subscribed to a topic, we create a new connection, a new session and, lastly, a new listener.

We would like to switch to a single connection model. Although I am able to do this easily in our code by sharing one connection object and creating a new session object per topic, we are unsure whether this is going to cause any issues without code.

My understanding is that the Tibco EMS client library is thread safe with regards to sharing a connection. In effect, a connection is just a pipe and the sessions can resuse the this pipe in a thread safe manner.

Is this assumption correct or is there more to this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The .NET EMS API is based on [JMS](http://dlc.sun.com/pdf/816-5904-10/816-5904-10.pdf). In JMS, the Connection and Session objects are specified to be thread-safe and can be reused within the program. You are quite correct in that the Connection object simply represent a network pipe to the EMS server. The EMS User's Guide states:

> A connection is a fairly heavyweight object, so most clients will create a connection once and keep it open until the client exits. Your application can create multiple connections, if necessary.

And regarding sessions:

> A Session is a single-threaded context for producing or consuming messages. You create Message Producers or Message Consumers using Session objects.

Essentially, unless you need very large volumes and are bumping into performance limitations, it's perfectly safe to use just one connection in your application. The session controls the transaction/acknowledgement semantics of any producers or consumers created within, but is again safe to reuse. I would probably use separate sessions for modules exist within the application with distinct life cycles (think separate deployment units within an application server).

Your EMS server installation will contain a samples directory with various code (something like *C:\tibco\ems\5.0\samples\cs*). The code in *csTopicSubscriber.cs* shows how to write a single-threaded topic consumer. There is no multi-threaded topic consumer example but *csMsgConsumerPerf.cs* demonstrates how to do it with queues.

Be sure to clean up any objects you create after you're done with them - e.g. close the topic consumer object, the session, and the connection when you're finished. Leaking handles without closing them can result in unpredictable behaviour when combined with prefetch and fault-tolerant reconnect settings.

Answer (score 0):

I think yes as long as sharing is within the same application (exe, binary).
We have shared same connection object, and used it as a singleton in our code.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with an earlier answer: the JMS Session must not be shared between threads, but the Connection can/should be. So one connection per application is ok (make sure you start/close it   only once - best before/after the individual threads creation).

And then create and use one Session per thread. Remember that when you close() a Session, it will block until all receive callbacks have really returned. So do NOT call close() from within a callback's onMessage().